# LINQ-Entity Date Part

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I had a method to get the date part of a date in my linq to entity.

```
DateTime plusDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;

query = query.Where(q => (q.Item2 >= date && q.Item2 < plusDateTime.Date));
```

A bit of a hack. I found that there are EntityFunctions that are available.

```
query = query.Where(q => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Item2) >= date);
```

This gets the date part only.

Comment: I just wanted to post this as it took me ages  to find and thought it would help someone else.

Comment: @Mark, you should post your solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just saved a few minutes. Although @CraigStuntz is right, you should put the answer down there.

Comment: Sweet! Didn't know about EntityFunctions. Saved me a lot of work.