# How can I divide a DateTime field into intervals using LINQ-to-Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sybase

I have the following line of code:

```
group p by new DateTime((p.DateTime.Value.Ticks / interval.Ticks) * interval.Ticks).TimeOfDay
```

This works great in LINQ-to-Objects but it will not work in LINQ-to-Entities. I have two quetsions:

- Why does it work? I don't understand how dividing the time by an interval and then multiplying it by that same interval magically converts my 12:37 to 12:30. My basic experience with math says that **(A/B)*B = A**. (Cleared up by @spencer in comments. Much thanks!)
- How can I reformat this line to work in LINQ-to-Entities?

Comment: Bad assumption. `(A/B)*B` doesn't necessarily equal `A` when dealing with integer division. e.g. `(3/2)*2==2` because 3/2, while truely equal to 1.5 in the real world, gets truncated to 1 in integer land.

Comment: @spender Ok, so how does dividing a time value by an interval and then multiplying it by that interval end up giving me the results I'm looking for? It really bothers me having something work but not knowing how exactly it got from A to B.

Comment: Same as above. I want to know where 3 lies on timeslices of 2 seconds. Thus (3/2)*2 gives 2, which would be the start of that slice.

Comment: @spender lol, wow. For some reason that simple fact didn't dawn on me. I was like "Uh... yeah it does. (A/B)*B ALWAYS equals A." Was way over-thinking it though and not taking into account that the result would get truncated.

Comment: This looks interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6830925/14357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime methods you are using can't be translated by l2e. Consider using the [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412643) class for supported time operations.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563) for more details.

For instance, say your interval were 60 seconds, I'm guessing you might do something like:

```
DateTime? start=new DateTime(2000,1,1); //start of first interval
...group p by 
    EntityFunctions
        .AddSeconds(
            start,
            (EntityFunctions
                .DiffSeconds(p.DateTime,start)/60)*60
         )
```

Comment: Well, I'm sure I'll have to use something like EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime or EntityFunctions.DiffSomething but I'm not sure how I would convert my current new DateTime(ticks) stuff to the EntityFunction format.

Comment: I'm a bit clueless here myself, but I've bluffed an answer above! You might need to use CreateDateTime in place of `start`, perhaps in a `let` clause.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing around with a lot of different ideas for a day or two now but can't seem to come up with something that works. I tried yours but didn't get the results I needed.

Comment: Figured it out and you were very close: `EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(start, (EntityFuctions.DiffSeconds(start, p.DateTime)/1800) * 1800)`. "start" for my database is `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTime.Utc)`. I dunno if it didn't work the first time simply because of the p.DateTime coming before start or if it was just me not setting the start field correctly but works like a charm now.